# The file is not sent to the mail. (Only path)

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have this codes:

```
        epost.From = new MailAddress("test.31@gmail.com");
        epost.To.Add(textBoxMail.Text.ToString());
        epost.Subject = textBoxSubject.Text.ToString();
        epost.Body = "c:\\Users\\Raşit\\AppData\\Local\\MyText.txt"; //But i have a problem :(

        SmtpClient smpt = new SmtpClient();

        smpt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test.31@gmail.com", "mypassword");
        smpt.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smpt.EnableSsl = true;
        smpt.Port = 587;

        smpt.Send(epost);
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

Then I Started Debugging and I saw this:

[image]

I want file only, I don't want path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:\\Users\\Raşit\\AppData\\Local\\MyText.txt");
epost.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```